# How to deploy Express.js MongoDB using .ejs to vercel

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to deploy a node express app with mongoDB using .ejs to vercel.

The structure of my folder is:

```
-models
-public
-temp-uploads
-uploads
-views
.env
app.js
db.js
firebase.js
package.json
router.js
vercel.json
```

-> models folder contain files that have funtions to put and get the data from MongoDB
-> public folder contain files like css and normal .js file
-> temp-uploads used to store temp the image to process
-> uploads used to store image procced to store to firebase storage
-> views is where all the front-end .ejs file located
-> app.js contains

```
let express = require("express");
let app = express();
let session = require("express-session");
let flash = require("connect-flash");
const formidableMiddleware = require("express-formidable-v2");
let sessionOptions = session({
  secret: "********",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 100 * 60 * 60 * 24,
    httpOnly: true,
  },
});
let router = require("./router");

app.set("views", "views");
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(flash());
app.use(sessionOptions);
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "25mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(express.json({ limit: "25mb" }));
app.use(formidableMiddleware());
app.use("/", router); //router se connected hai

module.exports = app;
```

-> db.js contains

```
let mongodb = require("mongodb");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();
let port = process.env.PORT;
if (port == null || port == "") {
  port = 3001;
}

mongodb.connect(
  process.env.CONNECTIONSTRING,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  function (err, client) {
    module.exports = client.db();
    let app = require("./app");
    let server = app.listen(port);
    server.keepAliveTimeout = 70000;
    server.headersTimeout = 75000;
  }
);
```

-> package.json contains

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "type": "module",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.x"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node db.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "start nodemon db",
    "watch2": "start nodemon db --ignore frontend-js --ignore public/ && start webpack --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "Nodejs",
    "MongoDB",
    "Excel"
  ],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "compress-images": "^2.0.5",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-redis": "^7.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.22.1",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "ejs": "^3.1.7",
    "exceljs": "^4.2.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-formidable-v2": "^2.2.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.1",
    "firebase": "^9.17.1",
    "formidable": "^2.1.1",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "gifsicle": "^5.2.1",
    "global": "^4.4.0",
    "mongo-sanitize": "^1.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.4",
    "mongoose": "^6.6.5",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15",
    "pngquant-bin": "^6.0.1",
    "validator": "^13.7.0",
    "webpack": "^5.41.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2"
  }
}
```

-> router.js file contains the api get, and post requests
-> vercel.json contains

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{
    "src": "db.js",
    "use": "@vercel/node"
  }],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have deployed, but after success of deploy it gives me "404 - not" found error

Please help me to deploy to vercel.

Comment: Anyone can help me with this issue, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your `db.js` to `index.js` and change this line:

```
app.set("views", "views");
```

to:

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

Or you can use https://render.com/, in my opinion it is one of the best free deployment platforms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, The renaming of db.js to index.js worked, but changing this line of code `app.set("views", "views");` to `app.set("views", "./views");` didnot worked, instead I have used this `app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));` and worked for me.

Comment: The deployment had successed, but when I login to the web app and click one of the nav links the app loads and logout me of the user session. In the Vercel logs page there is no error. Anyone can tell what could be the issue please thanks.